# Iframe Not Loading on Button Click

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried searching around with no luck.  I have a button group that will populate another button group once clicked on.  The second group of buttons is designed to populate iframes depending on which button is clicked.  However, the iframe will not populate.  What am I missing?

I'm also trying to figure out how to hide the selections of the other buttons once I select a new button up top.  If I click on "Cars" for instance, it will show the second group of buttons.  If I click on "Part Number", it will still keep the group of buttons from "Cars" as well as display the "Part Number" button group.

```js
window.onload = function() 
   { 
      document.getElementById('model1').style.display = 'none';
   };

   function button1function(id){

      if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'initial';
      }else{
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
      }
      }
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="mpi-options btn-group-md">
      <button type="button" class="mpi-box1" id="mpi-box1" value='hide/show'     onclick="button1function('model1')">CAR</button>
    </div>
  
    <form id="model1" class="taskList" style="display:none" onchange="showhide(this)">
      <input type = "button" value="What is my car's color?"/>
    </form>

 
  <div class="answer1 answers" style="width:100%;height:500px;display:none">
  <div id="model1">Please enter search information</div>
    <iframe src="https://www.chevrolet.com/"
     width="100%" height="500" style="border-color:#666666" id="myiframe" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://www.ford.com/"
     width="100%" height="500" style="border-color:#666666" id="myiframe1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() 
  { 
  document.getElementById('model1').style.display = 'none';
  };

  function button1function(id){

  if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'initial';
  }else{
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="mpi-options btn-group-md">
  <button type="button" class="mpi-box1" id="mpi-box1" value='hide/show' 
   onclick="button1function('model1')">CAR</button>
</div>

<form id="model1" class="taskList" style="display:none" 
 onchange="showhide(this)">
           <input type = "button" value="What is my car's color?"/>
</form>

<div class="answer1 answers" style="width:100%;height:500px;display:none">
<div id="1">Please enter search information</div>
<iframe src="https://www.chevrolet.com/"
                width="100%" height="500" style="border-color:#666666" 
 id="myiframe" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.ford.com/"
                width="100%" height="500" style="border-color:#666666" 
 id="myiframe1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, please reduce this in order to have a minimal example that reproduces your error.

Comment: @StevenStark, I attempted to reduce the amount of code.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This is still far too much. Reproduce only the issue you're trying to get help with, leave the rest behind.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem is the URLs you're trying to load into the iFrame.
It's a special setting which prevents a particular website from being displayed inside an iFrame.
If you take a look at the console, you'll see this error message:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.toyota.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

So you won't ever see Toyota's website in your iFrame. Try replacing it with something that resides on your own webserver.